# Need to query a Race Table Based on user ID

Tags: java, android, sql

I have three tables, user table, races table and user_races table. 
user races table stores race_id and user_id as Foreign Key referencing user_id from user table and race_id from race table. 
I need to query all races for a single user based on the user ID. 
My idea when designing this "to learn and practice programming races app"
doing this "relational database" was to query all races where user id was the given in the funtion I called "raceList(int userID)" but so far it did not work. SELECT Statement must be wrong... any help would be appreciated.

```
public List<Race> raceList(int userid){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM " + RACES_TABLE_NAME+"a INNER JOIN "+USER_RACES_TABLE_NAME+" b ON a.id=b.race_id WHERE b.user_id ="+userid;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    List<Race> raceLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    Race race;

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            race = new Race();
            race.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_ID)));
            race.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_NAME)));
            race.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_DATE)));
            race.setHost(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_HOST)));
            race.setHostWebsite(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_HOST_WEB)));
            race.setOfficer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_OFFICER)));
            race.setOfficerNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RACE_OFFICER_N)));
            raceLinkedList.add(race);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
    return raceLinkedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading some more about Joining querys found out that this was the right code

```
query = "SELECT * FROM userRaces LEFT JOIN races ON userRaces.race_id=races.id "
+"LEFT JOIN users ON userRaces.user_id=users.id WHERE userRaces.user_id="+userid;
```

and it worked great.